# Headless VirtualBox VM / phpvirtualbox cant add iso to VM

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed a Headless VirtualBox VM Host on my Ubuntu Server.

Install finished but then I test the software. It's a fresh install Ubuntu Server 22.04. However, nothing happens when I try to select ISO file to the VM Machine.

```
Choose a virtual optical disk file... (Loadning...)
```

[image]

Can someone help me out of this issue??